# Microsoft Access 2016 OLE Object & Binary export

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ole

I'm trying to write some VBA code to generate a text file containing SQL INSERT statements for all records in a table in an Access database (accdb). The table has an OLE Object field and a Binary field. I can't seem to get them written to the text file properly; I mostly get question marks(?). I've search for solutions and found some possible ideas but none worked.

If any one has suggestions, I will be very appreciative of any help that you can provide.

Miguel

Comment: Are you wanting to generate an `INSERT` statement with a binary literal?

Comment: I've done some reading, and as far as I can tell it isn't possible to have a binary-literal in an `INSERT INTO` statement for MS Access: the only way to add binary data is by using a binary parameter and supplying the actual value with DAO or ADO.

Comment: I've found some unsubstantiated claims that say they could insert binary `image`  (not the same thing as `OLE`-typed columns, AFAIK) by serializing them as a Win32 DIB and supplying them to JET as a Base64-encoded string literal - I might suggest that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an solution following some more searching:

```
Function ByteArrayToHex(B() As Byte) As String
    Dim n As Long, I As Long
    
    ByteArrayToHex = Space$(2 * (UBound(B) - LBound(B)) + 2)
    n = 1
    For I = LBound(B) To UBound(B)
       Mid$(ByteArrayToHex, n, 2) = right$("00" & Hex$(B(I)), 2)
       n = n + 2
    Next
    ByteArrayToHex = "0x" & ByteArrayToHex
End Function
```

Michael